# How to change views every 5 seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an app similar to the 7 Minute Workout where the screen changes after a certain amount of time.

Is it possible to have the all the screens in my storyboard and have them automatically move screens after 5 seconds?

Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`? And what language is this for?

Comment: On would guess you'd use some sort of a timer.  What have tried?  Have you looked at any of the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can make an `NSTimer` and have a segue triggered after 5 seconds.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
target:self
selector:@selector(switchView:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];

-(void)switchView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue Identifier" sender:self];
}
```

You can make different view controlers in your storyboard. Make a segue between them and name segue identifiers. Then, in your viewDidLoad method in each ViewController.m use the abowe code

Comment: Well I wouldn't pass in `NSString` into `performSeguqWithIdentifier:` as this will throw and error. You should pass in an instance of `NSString` and what about the code for `NSTimer`?